# Write pdf using prince library

Tags: php, princexml

I am using prince library to Convert HTML documents to PDF. In one scenario, user uploads pdf document and I've to write a specific part of the pdf using Prince.

I went through [Prince PHP Interface Class](https://www.princexml.com/doc/10/php/#php) but did not find suitable methods.

Is there any way to write pdf using Prince library? Any help will be appreciable.

Comment: The library seems to convert from HTML to PDF. I haven't looked through the documentation but, writing to an existing PDF is a whole different scope of what their product provides.

Comment: @Johan Seems you're correct. I guess ZendPdf can fulfill my requirement.